# Linear Algebra Span question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

Let $a, b, c$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. From what I understand, if $c\in \mathrm{Span}\{a,b\}$, then $b\in \mathrm{Span}\{a,c\}$.

Since they all fall on the same plane, I can't seem to find a counterexample

In what situation(s) would the statement be false?

Comment: c could be zero?

Comment: @Nameless that doesn't give a counter example $c = a+ b, b = c-a$

Comment: what if the c span (a,b) is true first then b spans (a,c)? Because if c= xa that makes the first part untrue. The question asks considering the c spans (a,b) as a precondition?

Comment: @mikevaiana, oh god what was I doing...

Comment: @Nameless I don't know, ;)

Answer (score 2):

If $c \in \operatorname{Span}(a,b)$, then there are constants $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$c = \alpha a + \beta b$$

Rearrange this and find

$$b = \frac{1}{\beta} \left(c - \alpha a\right)$$

Now this isn't valid for $\beta = 0$, so it hints pretty strongly at possible counterexamples. (That is: What happens if $c = \alpha a$?)

Comment: what if the c span (a,b) is true first then b spans (a,c)? Because if c= xa that makes the first part untrue. The question asks considering the c spans (a,b) as a precondition?

Comment: If c= xa + 0b then $c\in \text{Span}\{a,b\}$ by definition; it is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: so if c is span of a,b then does b have to span a,c?